# How to get a list of PLSQL objects that call functions?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I would like to get a list of PL/SQL objects (Procedures, Packages, etc.) that call a certain function.  Is there a way to do that?  Does it involve selecting from `dba_dependencies`?

Toad seems to implement what I want via the **Deps (Used By)** tab when Describing an object, but how would you construct a query to have similar results (recursion unneeded).

Comment: try to look in `dba_source` and in `all_source` and put in command line `text like "%nameFunction%"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the list from a particular schema,

```
SELECT name, type
FROM   user_source 
WHERE  lower(text) LIKE LOWER('%Your_Function_Name%');
```